# Redirect on select option with meteor

Tags: meteor, iron-router

I need some help with meteor. I've template with select options:

```
<select id="collapseFour" class="form-control collapse">
  {{#each examNum}}
    <option>{{this}}</option>
  {{/each}}
</select>
```

And I've helper that helps me in creating list of exam numbers:

```
Template.adminLayout.helpers({
  examNum: function() {
    var number = [];
    for(var i=1;i<=50;i++){
      number[i] = i;
    }
    return number;
  }  
});
```

I need to make page redirect to the specified exam page, when I choose one of the options. Like onchange, or href in a tag element. I know that it can be solved with helpers, so tried this:

```
Template.adminLayout.helpers({
  'change [type=select]': function(e,t){
    // page redirect
  },
});
```

But it doesn't work. What can choose the problem, any help will be appreciated!

Comment: This question was in the Triage queue. It was a borderline "Should be Improved" (for me), but I don't know HTML and Meteor well enough to judge it (so you got the benefit of the doubt). If the problem is not obvious, you should *Edit* your question and make it obvious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Already solved, just in case if somebody needs. Here is the template:

```
<select id="collapseFour" name="examNo" class="form-control collapse">
  {{#each examNum}}
    <option value="{{this}}">{{this}}</option>
  {{/each}}
</select>
```

Js file:

```
Template.adminLayout.events({
  'change #collapseFour': function(event, template) {
    no = template.find('[name=examNo]').value;
    Router.go('adminExamPage', {no: no});
  }
});
```

And router.js:

```
this.route('adminExamPage',{
    path: '/coordinator/exam/:no',
    layoutTemplate: 'adminLayout'        
});
```